# Synchronizing Word BuildingBlocks over network but with offline support

Tags: vba, templates, ms-office, ms-word

I have built a **custom BuildingBlock management system** for Word 2013 in VBA enabling users to categorize, filter and use BuildingBlocks more conveniently.

The blocks are stored in a `.dotm` template file which is attached to a `.docm` file with the management system code in it. The content of the latter is updated from time to time globally and each users local copy may contain individual content as well. All users should be able to create new blocks automatically available to all others. Also, working with one's local blocks should be possible anytime (online, offline), only for creating/deleting blocks a network connection is required.

Here's a graphic trying to explain the connections:

[image: Local and network files]

My **approach** was to copy the storage file from network to local on each opening of the local work file and before any changes are locally initiated. Right after a change, the network files get updated. That way, changes of other users most propably won't be overwritten (only if they occur on the same time) and all users have an up-to-date collection of blocks to work with.

The **problem:**
I cannot overwrite a file in use - as the work file references the `.dotm` block storage file, it gets opened in the background. Disattaching the template temporarly won't work either: I tried using

`ActiveDocument.AttachedTemplate = ""`

but this is critical unstable and won't be processed on the systems I tested on (different configurations). I have no idea why, but I can't rely on such a solution.

So here's my **question**:
Do you know a way to do this? Are there any best practices?

I appreciate any hint.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone interested in this topic: I had to create a workaround for this.

The template storing the building blocks needs to be closed to be overwritten, so I wrote a small **batch script** doing the updating after the work file is closed. To return to the last action or to finalize it, the batch file creates a temporary text file with exchange arguments which in turn can be read on work file open. Here's the batch file:

```
@echo off
:: Batch file for updating the local libraries [referenced as library and cat files in the following]
:: Parameters: 
::  %1 - caller file path
::  %2 - update scenario
::  %3 - local tool dir path
::  %4 - library file name
::  %5 - cat file name
::  %6 - network library dir path
::  %7 - tooldata folder name

SET n=0
SET f=0

IF "%~1"=="" (
  echo No arguments passed.
  Goto NoArguments
)

:: Build local and remote paths to the libraries
SET LocalLib=%~3%~4
SET LocalCat=%~3%~5
SET NetworkLib=%~6%~4
SET NetworkCat=%~6%~5

:: Wait for a maximum of 16 sec until the local library gets released.
:: If its still in use afterwards, abort the copy actions.

:Loop
SET /A n=n+1
IF %n% EQU 10 (
  Goto FileNotClosed
) ELSE (
  2>nul (
    >>%LocalLib% echo off
  ) && (SET f=1)
  IF %f% EQU 0 (
    Ping 1.1.1.1 -n 2 -w 1 | find /V "Ping" > nul
    Goto Loop
  ) ELSE (
     Goto StartCopy
  )
 )

:StartCopy
:: Calling document is closed so it should be save to copy the network libraries to the local destination
xcopy %NetworkLib% %LocalLib% /y /q
xcopy %NetworkCat% %LocalCat% /y /q

:FileNotClosed
:: Finally write results of the actions to a xargs.txt file
@echo scenario=%~2>"%~3%~7\xargs.txt"
IF %f% EQU 0 ((@echo success=0)>>"%~3%~7\xargs.txt") ELSE ((@echo success=1)>>"%~3%~7\xargs.txt")

:: Reopen the caller file
%1

:NoArguments
```

The problem arising with this solution is that any data created in the workfile is lost when closing the file. That's why I also needed to store any user form/ building block data in additional temporary files.

For example, creating a new building block works now as follows: The user inputs all neccessary information in the work file dialogs. When finished, the data gets saved in temporary files, the updater.bat gets started and the work file is shut down. The updater copies the most recent files and restarts the work file, which reads the update outcome from the besaid .txt file, finishes the creation, reuploads the local files to the network and cleans up the mess.